# Update Trigger Problema Fecha

Tags: mysql, date, trigger, distinct

estoy estancado en un trigger que necesito para un proyecto. Estas son las tablas involucradas:

```
datos_trabajadores
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id_tra        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | nombre_tra    | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | apellidos_tra | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | dni_tra       | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | telefono_tra  | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | falta_tra     | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | dias_tra      | int(255)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

datos_recogida
    +--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id_rec       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_tra_rec   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | id_var_rec   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | fecha_rec    | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | cantidad_rec | int(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

El caso, es que id_tra y id_tra_rec estan relacionadas, y necesito que el trigger sume 1 a dias_tra cada vez que se ingresa un registro en datos_recogida (respecto al id_tra_rec). El problema es que, un trabajador puede recoger cosas distintas el mismo dia, por lo tanto no puede sumar si la fecha es la misma (algo parecido a un select distinct).
Una ayudita?¿ :)

Comment: Prueba poniendo "IF exist", en caso de que exista un registro con la fecha de ese día, que no lo sume, te dejo link :"https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017"

Comment: No le pongas SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta eso no es válido, alcanza con que publiques la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCION FINAL (Espero que le sirva a alguien):

```
drop trigger if exists dias_tra;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER dias_tra AFTER INSERT ON datos_recogida FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE dias INT;
SET dias = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fecha_rec) AS diasmes FROM datos_recogida WHERE id_tra_rec=NEW.id_tra_rec);
UPDATE datos_trabajadores SET dias_tra = dias where id_tra=NEW.id_tra_rec;
END; $$
```